# Kaggle TPU NotFoundError for the GCS path

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, kaggle, tpu

I am trying to train a Neural Net on my own dataset in a kaggle kernel like this:

```
%%time
history = model.fit(train_dataset, 
                   steps_per_epoch=train_labels.shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE,
                   callbacks=[lr_callback],
                   epochs=EPOCHS,
                   validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

Before I enabled the TPU and set a path like this:

```
GCS_DS_PATH = KaggleDatasets().get_gcs_path('my-first-data') # you can list the bucket with "!gsutil ls $GCS_DS_PATH"
!gsutil ls $GCS_DS_PATH
clear_output()
```

I use:

tensorflow version 2.1.0
tensorflow.keras version 2.2.4-tf

However this is the error I receive. I ran the exact same code before with a dataset from a kaggle competition and it worked perfectly. Now that I am trying to run it on my own dataset, I get this issue. My data has the exact same structure as the competition data and the file Train_17.jpg from the error message is not missing (I checked).

I am wondering, if this has to do something with the TPU, since the data is read from a cloud bucket and my personal (but public!) kaggle dataset might not allow for that?

Do you have suggestions?

```
Train for 28 steps, validate for 5 steps

Epoch 00001: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to 1e-05.
Epoch 1/40
 1/28 [>.............................] - ETA: 59:20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    340                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    341                 training_context=training_context,
--> 342                 total_epochs=epochs)
    343             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    344 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    126         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    127       try:
--> 128         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    129       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    130         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     96     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     97     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 98                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     99 
    100   return execution_function

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    566 
    567   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 568       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    569       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    570 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    566 
    567   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 568       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    569       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    570 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in _non_none_constant_value(v)
    128 
    129 def _non_none_constant_value(v):
--> 130   constant_value = tensor_util.constant_value(v)
    131   return constant_value if constant_value is not None else v
    132 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/tensor_util.py in constant_value(tensor, partial)
    820   """
    821   if isinstance(tensor, ops.EagerTensor):
--> 822     return tensor.numpy()
    823   if not is_tensor(tensor):
    824     return tensor

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in numpy(self)
    940     """
    941     # TODO(slebedev): Consider avoiding a copy for non-CPU or remote tensors.
--> 942     maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    943     return maybe_arr.copy() if isinstance(maybe_arr, np.ndarray) else maybe_arr
    944 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _numpy(self)
    908       return self._numpy_internal()
    909     except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 910       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)
    911 
    912   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

NotFoundError: {{function_node __inference_distributed_function_519795}} Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 404 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "No such object: kds-f683341923266d33718e6f3ab31b298eb2f954595ee701388c328ce7/images/Train_17.jpg",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "No such object: kds-f683341923266d33718e6f3ab31b298eb2f954595ee701388c328ce7/images/Train_17.jpg",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
  }
}
'
     when reading metadata of gs://kds-f683341923266d33718e6f3ab31b298eb2f954595ee701388c328ce7/images/Train_17.jpg
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
```

Comment: It seems that the "No such object" error is thrown by the Cloud Storage API, could you please share the code that you are using to get the file from Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an incorrect path to access my data. My images were in "my-first-data/plant-pathology-2020-cropped-images/images"

```
GCS_DS_PATH = KaggleDatasets().get_gcs_path('my-first-data')
!gsutil ls $GCS_DS_PATH
```

shows that the bucket contains this "plant-pathology-2020-cropped-images" folder.
This is how you define the paths for the images to pass them to the model.

```
def format_path(st):
    return GCS_DS_PATH + '/plant-pathology-2020-cropped-images/images/' + st + '.jpg'
train_paths = df_train.image_id.apply(format_path).values
```